# Why does Salesforce has Trigger.isInsert or Trigger.isUpdate when Trigger.old !=Null would have worked?

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

Salesforce has context variables like Trigger.IsInsert just to understand if trigger is running for Insert scenarios. However, we could always have got this information by doing the NULL check on Trigger.Old or Trigger.OldMap

Example:

We always use it in below scenarios:

> Scenarios 1:
>       if(Trigger.isInsert){
>          method1();
>       }
>
> Scenarios 2:
>       if(Trigger.old == null){
>         method1();
>       }

In both the scenarios, decision/control statements are same and have the same complexity. What's the benefit of having it then?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, you get *significantly clearer semantics* when you check `if (trigger.isInsert)` rather than checking `if (trigger.old == null)`. It also adds consistency and completeness with the `isBefore` and `isAfter` attributes, which you could not check by inspecting the collection values.

Second of all, checking for the presence of `trigger.new` and `trigger.old` does not suffice to uniquely check all operations. For example, both `before insert` and `before undelete` have `trigger.old == null && trigger.new != null`.

Comment: To add, if the conditions for inserting change, then having those qualities in a function means the end user doesn't have to change their code at all.

Answer (score 5):

There are more trigger events than just `insert` and `update`. `Trigger.old` is also available in `delete` triggers (see [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)), so comparing `Trigger.old` to `null` is not sufficient by itself to identify which trigger event we are running in. Likewise, `Trigger.new` is available (without `Trigger.old`) in both `insert` and `undelete` context.

Even if we could derive the trigger event by making various comparisons between `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.old`, and `null`, it's clearer and more semantically meaningful to just write

```
if (Trigger.isInsert) {
```

rather than

```
if (Trigger.new != null && Trigger.old == null) {
```

In fact, we now have `Trigger.operationType` to even further streamline this type of code with constructs like

```
switch on (Trigger.operationType) {
    when BEFORE_INSERT {
        // do stuff...
    }
    when AFTER_UPDATE {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I was going to add in something about `trigger.operationType` but now that you have it here, I'll leave my answer as is.

Answer (score 4):

You can get Trigger.Old in Update and Delete context, so you cannot guarantee its insert just by adding a null check on Trigger.old.

Thats where isInsert ,isDelete,isUpdate,isUndelete comes in picture.

> ```
> Trigger.old Returns a list of the old versions of the sObject records.
> This sObject list is only available in update and delete triggers.
> ```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm